# Distributed Transaction on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, distributed, distributed-computing

I'm working on a distributed system that uses distributed transactions, which means that I may have a transaction that needs to edit multiple databases (on multiple servers) at the same time.

In my system there is a controller to manage the distribution.

the scenario that I want to satisfy is:
server A wants to initiate a distributed transaction. the participants are server A and server B. so server A sends a request to the controller to initiate a distributed transaction.
the controller opens a connection to server A and to server B and ask them to do local transactions. both server A and server B must reply the server that they are ready. the controller then sends commit to both server A and server B.

Do you have any advice for me to be able to build this distributed transaction ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can google two-phase commit, it is a very famous and useful protocol for distributed transactions, and this is the wiki from wikipedia [Two-phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)

Answer (score 0):

[Two phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) is what you want, as BitHigher mentions. It's also known as [XA transactions](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/c193). For MySQL specific operations, read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html).

Note that XA will come with its own complications, especially in cases of failures. Make sure you understand all the corner cases before attempting to use XA.