# rollback transactions on multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple PDO objects, referring to different databases on different servers. I need to be able to rollback all transactions in case of error at any step.

In fact, I want to have something like this:

```
try {
    $db1Connector->beginTransaction();
    $db2Connector->beginTransaction();
    
    //some functionality
    
    $db1Connector->commit();
    $db2Connector->commit();
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    $db1Connector->rollback();
    $db2Connector->rollback();
}
```

I have this functionality in my code, but it seems it does not work correctly. I noticed some cases that only one of the transactions is rollbacked. I guess this problem occurs when `$db1Connector->commit()` or `$db2Connector->commit()` fails.

Comment: "1. Is it possible?" -- Have you tried it? Have you encountered a problem that makes you believe it wasn't? What was the exact problem? [Edit] the question and elaborate.

Comment: @sticky bit: The OP has shown code and does not know the concept of distributed transaction. What added value does your policing represent?

Comment: Are `dbConnector1` and `dbConnector2` pointing at different database servers? or different databses within the same server? The second case its probably better to merge it all into one transaction across multiple databases. Your main problem with your current code is that after `db1Connector->commit()` occurs, it can't be rolled back if `db2Connector` failes to commit.

Comment: @danblack I updated the question. They are on different servers.

Comment: @MiladBarazandeh As pointed out by danblack you may be better avoiding distributed transactions on MySql even if in theory it should work. The alternative is to specifically implement a mechanism that will allow a recovery in case of single transaction failure. Such mechanism would be specific to what you are trying to do in the transaction and you should ensure that the concerned data is only updated via your code.

Comment: See https://hackernoon.com/fescar-a-distributed-transaction-solution-open-sourced-by-alibaba-f70c9b4c72a1

Comment: This may help even better https://www.grahamlea.com/2016/08/distributed-transactions-microservices-icebergs/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use a distributed transaction. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772363/distributed-transaction-on-mysql#:~:text=so%20server%20A%20sends%20a,server%20A%20and%20server%20B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772363/distributed-transaction-on-mysql#:%7E:text=so%20server%20A%20sends%20a,server%20A%20and%20server%20B).

Comment: note while XA transactions have existing for quite a while, avoid trying to combine then with newer features of MySQL. Its a very tricky concept to implement and there are numerous bug reports still open on it across various scenarios.